# Javascript prototype through Object.create()

Tags: javascript, prototype

```
var someObj = function() { }
var p = new someObj();

alert(someObj.prototype);   // This works
alert(p.prototype);         // UNDEFINED, but why?

someObj.prototype.model= "Nissan";
alert(p.model);             // This works! I understand the dynamic nature of prototypes, but doesn't that mean that p.prototype === someObj.prototype?
```

Why is this so? Since "p" is an instance of "someObj", why is the prototype undefined? I mean, when I add a property to "someObj" prototype, it is accessible to "p", so why is the prototype not accessible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The important thing here is that the `prototype` property of function objects **is not** the prototype of an object. It's the object that will be assigned as the prototype of an object you create via `new someObj`. Prior to ES5, you can't directly access the prototype of an object; as of ES5, you can, via [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.2.3.2).

Re

> `alert(p.prototype);         // UNDEFINED, but why?`

The reason is that the `p` object doesn't have a property called "prototype". It has an underlying prototype, but that's not how you access it.

All function objects have a property called `prototype` so that if they're used as constructor functions, we can define what the properties of the underlying prototype of the objects created by those constructors will be. This may help:

```
function Foo() {
}
Foo.prototype.answer = 42;

console.log(Foo.prototype.answer); // "42"
var f = new Foo();
console.log(f.answer); // "42"
```

That last line works like this:

1. Get the `f` object.
2. Does `f` have its **own** property called "answer"?
3. No, does `f` have a prototype?
4. Yes, does the prototype have its **own** property called "answer"?
5. Yes, return the value of that property.

You've mentioned [`Object.create`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.2.3.5) in the title of your question. It's important to understand that `Object.create` is quite separate from constructor functions. It was added to the language so that if you preferred not to use constructor functions, you didn't have to, but could still set the prototype of an object — directly, when you create that object.

Answer (score 6):

That's because `prototype` is a property of the constructor function, not a property of itself. However, the `prototype` object has a reference to the constructor, so you can access an object's `prototype` via its `constructor` property:

```
function Foo() {}

Foo.prototype.foo = "bar";

var c = new Foo;

console.log( c.constructor === Foo );   // true
console.log( c.constructor.prototype ); // { foo: 'bar' }
```

However, this will not work if you overwrite the initial `prototype` property of the constructor function:

```
function Foo() {}

// I overwrite the prototype property, so I lose the initial reference
// to the constructor.
Foo.prototype = {
  foo: "bar"
};

var c = new Foo;

console.log( c.constructor === Foo );    // false
console.log( c.constructor === Object ); // true
console.log( c.constructor.prototype );  // {}
```

That's why you're better off using the new [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) method introduced in ES5.

```
function Foo() {}

Foo.prototype = {
  foo: "bar"
};

var c = new Foo;

console.log( c.constructor === Foo );    // false
console.log( c.constructor === Object ); // true
console.log( c.constructor.prototype );  // {}
console.log( Object.getPrototypeOf(c) ); // { foo: 'bar' }
```

Another solution would have been to make sure you restore the `constructor` reference on the prototype:

```
function Foo() {}

// Overwriting the initial prototype    
Foo.prototype = {
  constructor: Foo, // restore the constructor reference
  foo: "bar"
};
```

Comment: I found an extremely useful blogpost, which, combine with this answer, clears a lot of confusion about the whole prototype madness. http://blog.sklambert.com/javascript-prototype/ the diagrams helps a lot in understanding this answer. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

p.prototype doesn't work because in this case p = someObj.prototype.

Basically when you use the new operator what happen is that the constructor someObj is used to initialize a new object. Which means it returns an object which have the properties and methods of the prototype of the constructor.

Thus p = someObj.prototype and p.prototype is undefined as p is not a constructor.

This article might help explains this more

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/javascript-prototypical-inheritance-explained.html#fbid=A2ikc3JLxeD

Comment: Per Crowder's answer, the prototype is there and is accessible, through the use of Object.getPrototypeOf(p). If my understanding is correct, that the properties and methods get copied to new instances of objects, but that does not mean that p === someObj.prototype. It means p.prototype === someObj.prototype

Answer (score 1):

`p` is an *instance* of `someObj`. The prototype belongs to the constructor. You can retrieve `p`'s constructor prototype using `p.constructor.prototype`

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, constructors, and in fact all functions get a prototype property. An objects (that is, a set of key-value pairs), does not have a prototype property. In your example above,

```
var someObj = function() { } // this is a function, so it has a prototype property
var p = new someObj(); // this is an instance object, so it doesn't
```

That's why someObj.prototype is defined, but p.prototype is not.